# What is the difference between "formula validity" and "theorem proving" (e.g. in First Order Logic)?

Tags: logic, first-order-logic, proof-theory

What is the difference between proving formula validity (e.g. as is done by SMT solvers) and between proving formula to be a theorem (e.g. as is done by the automatic theorem provers or proof assistants acting in the capability of automatic theorem proving)?

I have hard that theorem proving can be reduced to the solving multiple formula validity problem, is it so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference is validity is a semantic concept, while provability is a syntactic concept. That these define equivalent relationships on formulas need not be true in general. That they *are* equivalent for some logics (many of the ones we typically use, and particularly classical first-order logic) is the content of the soundness and completeness theorems, particularly the completeness theorem.

SMT solvers don't show validity though. They show satisfiability. That's literally what the name stands for: "Satisifiability Modulo Theories". Validity is that a formula is satisfiable for all models. Satisfiability is that is satisfiable for some model. If the negation of the statement whose validity you wish to verify falls into the fragment of logic supported by an SMT solver using a decidable theory, then you can check for the unsatisifiability of the negated statement to verify the validity of the original statement.

When you can just stick your original formula into an SMT solver and check its validity, it's not the SAT part but the Theories part that allows that. And that's just because they utilize a decision procedure for the relevant theory. A (fully) automatic theorem prover is itself just a semi-decision procedure. Proof assistants work differently even if you use tactics to automate them. A (semi-)decision procedure is a black box that outputs true or false (or "I don't know"), and you're just supposed to trust that it's right. Proof assistants, on the other hand, only check proofs, and so a tactic in such implementing a (semi-)decision procedure actually produces a proof that the statement is true or false (or it fails). Many stand-alone decision procedures will produce some form of certificate for the result, but many do not and truly are just black boxes.

Comment: There's also a hybrid approach where you implement a decision or semi-decision algorithm, then formally verify that the algorithm (and its implementation) are correct.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the difference you are trying to get at is that proving the validity of a statement $\phi$ is demonstrating that $\vDash \phi$, while theorem proving usually involves showing that a single statement $\phi$ follows from a given set of statements $\Gamma$, i.e. demonstrating that $\Gamma \vDash \phi$.

As such, 'theorem proving' can indeed be reduced to 'validity proving' as we have that $\Gamma \vDash \phi$ if and only if $\vDash (\phi_1 \land ... \land \phi_n) \rightarrow \phi$ where $\Gamma = \{ \phi_1,  ... , \phi_n \}$